# Conectar MS SQL em PGADMIN

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

Olá, boa tarde!

Preciso saber se há alguma ferramenta, script ou qualquer outra coisa de onde eu possa ter o seguinte cenário:

Tenho um banco MS SQL porém preciso manipula-lo através do pgAdmin (postgres).

Cnosegui fazer o inverso utilizando o MS Linked Server SQL, porém, para postgres não achei nenhuma forma de um tipo de "Linked Server" para postgres.

Answer (score 0):

O Spoon (Data Integration) vai te ajudar nesse sentido. Ele é mais voltado DW, mas você pode criar esse tipo de serviço tranquilo.

É uma ferramenta incrível da empresa Pentaho.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4xdD2BUTEk&list=PLG_hvke1jYoQ1YFB4x3QKg0I0Qbk9--QD

O link acima vai te ajudar assim como me ajudou. Pena que a qualidade das aulas não estão legais.